# deploy .war file to tomcat8 ubuntu16.04

Tags: tomcat8, war

I followed this tutorial for setting the tomcat8 on ubuntu 16.04:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have configured tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml, added arsys.xml in tomcat/works/CATALINA/localhost/. I have updated .bashrc by setting CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

It is now all set up and now when I click on Manager App, I get Tomcat Web Application Manager windows. Thereafter browsing the required .war file under the section WAR file to deploy, after clicking Deploy button I get that 'This site can't be reached'. (Google-Chrome)

What could be the possible reason for it? What shall I do to resolve it?

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working for you. But I installed tomcat 8 with `sudo apt install tomcat8`. After that I just move the .war files to the `webapps` folder of my tomcat installation dir.

Comment: I didn't move the war file to webapps folder, now atleast it is being displayed in Applications in Tomcat Web Application Manager. Thank you @gromit190.
Now when I click start for it, the message on top says 
FAIL - Application at context path [/war_file] could not be started.